# Combine images and draw text on each image with animation xfade

Tags: ffmpeg, video, audio, video-production

I am using ffmpeg to merge multiple images and an audio to produce a video. I am using drawtext and xfade with dissolve transition. My ffmpeg command is given below.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img0.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img1.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img2.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img3.jpg -t 20 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex " 
[0]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=4,drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20,setsar=1[v0];
[1]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=4,drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20,setsar=1[v1];
[2]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=4,drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20,setsar=1[v2];
[3]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=4,drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20,setsar=1[v3];
[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[vid]" -map "[vid]" -map 4:a -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

I am getting below error when executing this command.

```
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_xfade_9
```

Answer (score 1):

`xfade` requires two input video streams. You are using only one. It has to fade from a video and into another. Use a black `color` filter for the other.

Comment: Yes you are right it requires two inputs but It does not necessarily have to be videos, it can be images too. I came up with an answer here. https://superuser.com/questions/1819911/combine-images-and-draw-text-on-each-image-with-animation-xfade